# Long Comments in JAVA

Tags: java, android

Is it ok if I use Comments with long dashes like this to seperate my code?

Will it affect the performance of my application or any other aspect?I was thinking to do this in all of my activities.

```
   radioSection.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
          @Override
          public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group1, int checkedId1) {
              switch (checkedId1) {
                  case R.id.rbSr:
                      section = "SR";
                      break;
                  case R.id.rbJr:
                      section = "JR";
                      break;
              }
          }
      });
//----------------------------------------------------------------//----------------------------------------------------------------
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
//----------------------------------------------------------------//----------------------------------------------------------------
   next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             String name1 = FullName.getText().toString().trim();
             String name2 = DOB.getText().toString().trim();

            if(radioGender.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1 || radioSection.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1 || name1.isEmpty() || name2.isEmpty() || subsection.equals("Select Sub-Section") || subject.equals("Select Subject")){
                 Toast.makeText(ADDdetails.this, "Enter Details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }else{
                 updateUserDetails();
             }
         }
     });
//----------------------------------------------------------------//----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that "in all of my activities"? Because your code would be easier to understand? Then you should add more methods, classes, variables etc. and give them proper names that makes clear what the thing does and what it is used for. These comments are completely useless.

Comment: You should comment according to the coding convention that you use. I find this type of line separator jarring (no pun intended).

Comment: @luk2302 Thanks for your advice! I will try to make my code look more cleaner.

Comment: I very occasionally make separating comments, for example between groups of methods. My tips would be: (1) include some headline that briefly describes what comes after the comment. (2) Indent the (start of the) comment (the `//`) with the rest of the code so it doesn’t disturb the eye when trying to read the structure through looking at the indentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition, comments don't affect execution of the program.

From [this tutorial from Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/),

> **Comments are ignored by the compiler** but are useful to other programmers.

Whether it's OK or not from a stylistic perspective is a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 0):

For your own personal use perspective it'll be fine. The blocks of commented code will be ignored. When it comes to commenting in a team environment it's important to be uniform with what the team wants.

Answer (score -1):

It will not affect application, but it will affect compiler because it has to extract comments from code.

Comment: In what way will it affect the compiler?

Comment: The compiler will take (an unmeasurable amount of) time to determine that his line is a comment and that it should therefore be ignored. @luk2302

Comment: The extra compilation time is some very tiny fraction of a second, so who cares?

Comment: Yes, it takes time, but a negligable amount of time. Following this logic removing line breaks, white spaces and renaming every field, variable and method to a single character would be preferred. But what matters is readability and if a comment adds readability then it is a good idea (these comments really are not) and the <1ms impact on compile time should not be considered at all.

Comment: @luk2302 On a standard development computer we’re talking *much* less than a millisecond, far down in the microsecond range. It’s really negligible (that was the word I was searching my mind for, thank you for bringing it in).